# Difference about performance betwen Named parameters and Positional parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, parameter-passing

I know that comparing with a normal `Select`, putting the values directly into the `SQL` statements, like this way:

```
Statement command = connection.createStatement( "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = "+ nameVar);
```

Doing that with `JDBC` and positional parameters, like this:

```
String statment= "SELECT * from Users WHERE name=? and pass =?";
sentence = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
sentence.setString(1, nameVar);
sentence.setString(2, passVar);
```

Is better for several things, like avoid `SQL` injection, and also uses less memory (for caching the execution plan only once) and performance (for not doing the same execution plan again and again)

But if you have a lots of "`?`" may be difficult to correlate the parameter with the variable, and that can cause an error.

My question is,  if there is a difference between doing the positional parameters as above with doing "named parameters" like this:

```
String statment= "SELECT * from Users WHERE name=:nameParam and pass =:passParam";
sentence = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
sentence.setString("nameParam", nameVar);
sentence.setString("passParam", passVar);
```

Because is easier and can skip errors

**UPDATE**

by the comments seems that only using JPA/Hibernate can use `:parameters`. Well The question remains. There is any difference using Hibernate?

Comment: The version with :nameParam is only in JPA/Hibernate I haven't seen it in jdbc.

Comment: @RaduToader . Ok and.. There is a differnece using Hibernate?

Comment: The difference in performance will be negligible. Just use what feels better to you. And you can always do a benchmark if you're truly worried about any performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out you are building a PreparedStatement so that the DB can cache it's execution plan etc. So that is where all the performance gain comes from when the driver actually talks to the DB.

The other benefits are for the code. It is DRY-er (Do not Repeat Yourself) you can prevent SQL injection attacks as you can validate the params and they can't add "structural changes" to the SQL. You can keep a ref to the PreparedStatement Object so no need to re-create it etc etc.

But you are doing this on both cases, so the main benefits are the same. Under the covers an Array of params is passed to the Driver to run the prepared statement.

Positional params will most likely just index into the Array (depending on your Drivers' implementation) whereas named params maintain a map of name to position and generate the correct array when required.

Given that the number of params in a SQL statement tends to be small (can usually count them on one or two hands) creating the array is very fast, and negligible compared to the cost of running the query over the network to the DB.

So IMHO use whichever helps you reason about your code best. The performance difference is minuscule.

Comment: OK, thank you. My question was because I can't imagine myself using "?" instead of named params. It has no sense, is a lot easier to not missing a param or having an error and is more legible

Comment: Its a matter of personal syle and Use case IMHO. Normally I use a lib to abstract me from the underlying JDBC so I don't have these issues (just different ones ;-) ) but I can see a use case where you may receiving parameters in an array from an automated match system, then a loop over the array to set the values from the index position in the array to the SQL position may be justified (just remember to +1 to the array index as SQL index starts at 1 not 0 ), But if it's code for a one off specific input then I'd probably use named params or some variation to prevent me messing up :-)  Cheers